# Issue a command in each directory

Tags: bash, shell, cd-command

I have 3 directories: `dir1` contains two subdirs. In every subdir there is a slackbuild.
I want to build all slackbuilds, staying in the parent directory.
I have tried

```
(cd *;sh *ld)
```

But it only builds the first slackbuild in first subdir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `for`:

```
for i in */; do (cd "$i" && sh *ld); done
```